# C# WebRequest 400 Error when trying GET orderBy with firebase, works fine without orderby

Tags: c#, firebase, sql-order-by, webrequest

So, I am trying to get a list of objects from the firebase online database with the help of a WebRequest, whcih works fine, but when I try to query it with orderyBy="Price"&startAt=2 then the request gives me a 400 error and I can't understand why. Here is the code

```
private static string url = "https://project-name.firebaseio.com/Services.json?orderBy=\"Price\"&startAt=2"; 



 public static async Task<List<Service>> GetServices()
    {
        List<Service> services = new List<Service>();
        JObject j;
        var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url.ToString());
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            var json = (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());

            dynamic deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            j = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)(deserialized);
            try
            {
                foreach (System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken> obj in j)
                {
                    Service s = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Service>(obj.Value.ToString());
                    services.Add(s);
                }
                return services;
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException exception)
            {
                return new List<Service>();
            }
        }


    }
```

Please help!

Comment: Do you have an index on "Price"? [Indexes are not required for development **unless you are using the REST API.**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this bug, apparently what I was supposed to do was edit the rules of the Firebase Realtime Databse to have the index.On property. For anybody who's getting this error, please look out

[image]